# Ionic 3 footer is placed above the keypad in mobile devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to ionic. 
I have an app as follows

home.ts

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Headdddder</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

When i am running this app in a device then the footer is placed above the keyboard. How to remove it and place at the last.

In my app.ts my code is as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, keyboard: Keyboard) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** run `sudo cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard` from project directory.

**Second:** Then disable the keypad scrolling using code:

```
keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

> The final ts code will be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, keyboard: Keyboard) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to add it app.ts, and it should be called after onDeviceReady

Comment: Don't forget to add the plugin

Comment: Ahmed I don't find app.js in my project. I am working on ionic 3 with angular and typescript

Comment: please provide the name of the ts files. and app.js is my mistake. it will be app.ts

Comment: Ahmed would u please provide the plugin link.

Comment: run command **sudo cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard**

Comment: Please add your ts code also, then I can add more comments.

Comment: I have edited the question @Ahmed. But i am not able to get the required output that is footer is placed above keyboard when i try to enter some thing in input tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171297/discussion-between-roopteja-and-i-ahmed).